# how to create a folder in android External Storage Directory?

Tags: android, directory

I cannot create a folder in android External Storage Directory.

I have added permissing on manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is my code:

```
 String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString()+ "/Shidhin/ShidhiImages";
  System.out.println("Path  : " +Path );
  File FPath = new File(Path);
  if (!FPath.exists()) {
        if (!FPath.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("***Problem creating Image folder " +Path );
        }
  }
```

Comment: Try this:) hope it will help u. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41160319/7200297

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
String folder_main = "NewFolder";

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();
}
```

If you wanna create another folder into that :

```
File f1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + folder_main, "product1");
if (!f1.exists()) {
    f1.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated, you can used alternative getExternalFilesDir or others.

Comment: @Seyid-KananBagirov Please be specific when give answers. ```getExternalFilesDir``` gets cleared when the app in removed on its data gets cleared. So, what are the "others" methods?

Answer (score 13):

The difference between `mkdir` and `mkdirs` is that `mkdir` does not create nonexistent parent directory, while `mkdirs` does, so if `Shidhin` does not exist, `mkdir` will fail. Also, `mkdir` and `mkdirs` returns true only if the directory was created. If the directory already exists they return false

Answer (score 10):

**getexternalstoragedirectory()** is already deprecated. I got the solution it might be helpful for you. (it's a June 2021 solution)

Corresponding To incliding Api 30, Android 11 :

Now, use this commonDocumentDirPath for saving files.

**Step: 1**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Step: 2**

```
public  static  File commonDocumentDirPath(String FolderName){
    File dir = null ;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        dir = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+ "/"+FolderName );
    } else {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+FolderName);
    }   
    return  dir ;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

The use of [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment) now is deprecated since API level 29, the option is using:

[Context.getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).

Example:

```
void createExternalStoragePrivateFile() {
    // Create a path where we will place our private file on external
    // storage.
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");

    try {
        // Very simple code to copy a picture from the application's
        // resource into the external file.  Note that this code does
        // no error checking, and assumes the picture is small (does not
        // try to copy it in chunks).  Note that if external storage is
        // not currently mounted this will silently fail.
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.balloons);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        os.write(data);
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
        // not currently mounted.
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    }
}

void deleteExternalStoragePrivateFile() {
    // Get path for the file on external storage.  If external
    // storage is not currently mounted this will fail.
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");
    file.delete();
}

boolean hasExternalStoragePrivateFile() {
    // Get path for the file on external storage.  If external
    // storage is not currently mounted this will fail.
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");
    return file.exists();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can create a folder in android External Storage Directory.

I have added permissing on manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is my code:

```
String folder_main = "Images";

File outerFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);

File inerDire = new File(outerFolder.getAbsoluteFile(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

if (!outerFolder.exists()) {

    outerFolder.mkdirs();

}
if (!outerFolder.exists()) {

    inerDire.createNewFile();

}
```

- `outerFolder.mkdirs();`   // This will create a Folder
- `inerDire.createNewFile();`    // This will create File (For E.g .jpg
  file)

Answer (score 1):

we can Create Folder or Directory on External storage as :

```
 String myfolder=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+fname;
     File f=new File(myfolder);
     if(!f.exists())
     if(!f.mkdir()){
     Toast.makeText(this, myfolder+" can't be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
     Toast.makeText(this, myfolder+" can be created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and if we want to create Directory or folder on Internal Memory then we will do :

```
File folder = getFilesDir(); 
File f= new File(folder, "doc_download"); 
f.mkdir();
```

But make Sure you have given Write External Storage Permission.
And Remember that if you have no external drive then it choose by default to internal parent directory.
I'm Sure it will work .....enjoy code

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a folder inside your app directory in your storage.

**Step 1 : Add Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Step 2 : Add the following**

```
private String createFolder(Context context, String folderName) {

    //getting app directory
    final File externalFileDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);

    //creating new folder instance
    File createdDir = new File(externalFileDir.getAbsoluteFile(),folderName);

    if(!createdDir.exists()){

    //making new directory if it doesn't exist already
        createdDir.mkdir();

    }
    return finalDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" +  System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is raw but should be enough to get you going
// create folder external   located in Data/comexampl your app  file

```
    File folder = getExternalFilesDir("yourfolder");

        //create folder Internal

   
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath( ) + "/RICKYH");


    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Make Dir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

FPath.mkdirs();
(See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)

and then just save the file as needed to that path, Android OS will create all the directories needed.
You don't need to do the exists checks, just set that flag and save.
(Also see : [How to create directory automatically on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card)

Comment: Chris, I believe it's File.mkdirs(), not FPath?

Comment: The code in the posters example has a variable call FPath , hence FPath.mkdirs();

Answer (score 0):

I found some another thing too :
I had the same problem recently, and i tryed abow solutions and they did not work...
i did this to solve my problem :
I added this permission to my project manifests file :

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

(plus READ and WRITE permissions) and my app just worked correctly.

Answer (score -1):

try {

String filename = "SampleFile.txt";
    String filepath = "MyFileStorage";

```
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    myData = myData + strLine;
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          inputText.setText(myData);
            response.setText("SampleFile.txt data retrieved from External Storage...");
        }
    });

    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else {
        myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
    }
```