# HTML or JAVA command for creating a Folder on an Android phone via app

Tags: java, android, html, directory

Apologies if this seems like a stupid question, but I'm not a programmer by a long shot, and have been thrown into the deep end with regards to solving this problem.

The company that I just started working for used one of those "online app creation" services to build an app using their templates. The app they created was one of those "romance frame" type of apps where you take a pic and then apply a romantic mask over it. You can then save the pic to your gallery, or share it via social apps.

Everything works fine, except for the save to gallery. However, when I used the app tester (supplied by online app building company) to test the app before building the APK, it worked fine. I realized that when you use the app tester, it creates a folder called **PhotoEffect** on your phone. It then works fine. If you don't use the tester, abd simply upload the APK to Google Play (or install directly to your phone), it does not create the folder. Everything thus works, except for the SAVE TO GALLERY feature.

I basically want to know if there is a Java or HTML command that will create the folder for me when the app loads? I'm even willing to stick in a "PATCH" button that executes the command once the button is pushed. Not the optimum solution, but much better than an app that's not working.

Once the folder has been created, the app works fine from there onwards, so it only needs to check if the **PhotoEffect** folder exists, and if not, create it.

Oh yes... the app does have permission to write to the SD Card, but I'd prefer if the folder could be created on the phone instead? If not, I'll be fine with a SD Card-based solution as well :)

Any assistance would really be appreciated!

Take care,
Len

Comment: may this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781213/how-to-create-a-folder-in-android-external-storage-directory

Comment: Stick the piece of code in the link given by Pavan into the onCreate() method of your app.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a mil!!! Gonna try it and let you know how it turns out :)