# How to Create a folder in external sdcard in Android 4.4.2(Kitkat) API level 19

Tags: android, directory, android-sdcard

I try a lot to create a folder in SD card in android 4.4.2 version.
i try the following code

```
 String dirName="Test";
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), dirName);
        boolean status = file.mkdir();
                    if (status)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Directory created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory create failed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but it creates a folder in internal storage.

and I try another code is

```
  String path=System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
                File file=new File(path +"/Test123");
                file.mkdir();
```

it creates a folder in External SDCARD in android 4.1 but not in android 4.4.2

So how can i create a folder in External sdcard in android 4.4.2??
        If anyone know please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a folder in android External Storage Directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781213/how-to-create-a-folder-in-android-external-storage-directory)

Comment: 'but it creates a folder in internal storage. '. Don't believe you. Please tell the value of 'file.getAbsolutePath()'.

Comment: file.getAbsolutePath() gives the path of External SDCard but it does not create a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that

> Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in
>   order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace. Any files that are
>   private to the application should be placed in a directory returned by
>   Context.getExternalFilesDir, which the system will take care of
>   deleting if the application is uninstalled.

where with `top-level directory` they mean the return value of `Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Using  `getExternalFilesDir` you will have

```
 File file = new File (getExternalFilesDir(null), dirName);
 if (!file.exists()) {
   boolean status = file.mkdir();
   if (status) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory create failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 }
```

also you should be aware of the fact that `mkdir()` returns false if the directory already exists

Comment: It creates folder in our applications folder inside the internal storage.

Comment: it does, and accordingly to the documentation, that is the folder you should use

Comment: It creates a folder but inside internal storage. not in external sdcard.

Comment: it creates a folder inside `/sdcard/Android/data`

Comment: it creates a folder inside /sdcard/android/data/<packagename>

Comment: yes exactly.  Stick with that and pollute the sdcard's root

Comment: we are not able to create the folder in root of sdcard. we can only create a folder in package name folder in android 4.4.2(kitkat).

Answer (score 1):

This should be self-explanatory.

```
String folderName = "NewFolder";

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                folderName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
```

Make sure you have added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Credits to [Dhaval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2633467/dhaval)

Comment: You posted the same code as OP did. And even without checking results. So what does that help?

Comment: Already used this bit of code @greenapps. Already works. Edited to give proper credit.

Comment: I already added this permission in mwnifest file. but it does not create a folder in android 4.4.2